# How to serialize double Json Array with JSon.net C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have some Json that looks like that :

```
{
    "result":
    [
        [
            {
                "CODE_DOC":"1",
                "NOM_DOC":"doc1.pdf",
                "CODE_CAT":"1",
                "VERSIONS":
                [
                    {
                    "CODE_VRS":"1",
                    "CODE_FIC":"1",
                    "NOM_VRS":"1",
                    "NOM_FIC":"doc1.pdf",
                    "LOG_PERS":"zzzz",
                    "DATE_ENT":"1492179997"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "CODE_DOC":"2",
                "NOM_DOC":"doc2.pdf",
                "CODE_CAT":"2",
                "VERSIONS":
                [
                    {
                        "CODE_VRS":"2",
                        "CODE_FIC":"5",
                        "NOM_VRS":"45",
                        "NOM_FIC":"doc2.pdf",
                        "LOG_PERS":"jajaja",
                        "DATE_ENT":"1492161426"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

And I want to get a list of objects, that would be like :

```
public class Document
{
    int codeDoc;
    string nomDoc;
    int codeCat;
    Dictionary<String, String> versions;
}
```

but the problem is that I don't know how to do with that double array at the beginning. Does anyone know how I can do that? 
Thank you, have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem on how to pass the double array at the beginning, add an index of zero to JToken. Here is my example, first lets create our object class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class JsonDoc
{
    //I am adding an index on constructor for looping purposes
    public JsonDoc(string json, int index)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

        //Add an index of zero so that it will read the result node
        JToken jResult = jObject["result"][0];

        codedoc = (string)jResult[index]["CODE_DOC"].Value<string>();
        nomdoc = (string)jResult[index]["NOM_DOC"].Value<string>();
        codecat = (string)jResult[index]["CODE_CAT"].Value<string>();
        versions = jResult[index]["VERSIONS"].ToArray();
    }

    //This constructor will get the length of the array under result node
    public JsonDoc(string json)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken jResult = jObject["result"][0];
        intCount = jResult.Count();
    }

    public string codedoc { get; set; }
    public string nomdoc { get; set; }
    public string codecat { get; set; }
    public Array versions { get; set; }
    public int intCount { get; set; }
}
```

Then we read the Json data, on this case I put it on a file then use StreamReader to read it. The exact data is the same as your example. Then loop it twice since your data contains two objects.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Folder\json.json"))
        {
            string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
            JsonDoc jSon = new JsonDoc(json);

            //This will get the length of the array under result node
            int intCount = jSon.intCount;
            List<JsonDoc> lstResult = new List<JsonDoc>();
            for (int x = 0; x < intCount; x++)
            {
                lstResult.Add(new JsonDoc(json, x));
            }
        }
```

The resulting data would be a list of two objects with an array of versions:

[image]

Comment: This solution seems to work , but the thing is I don't know how many objects I'll get in the JSON, and when I try looping I always end up having "iterator out of range", how can I do this loop for any number of objects ?

Comment: Hi @Louuss, I updated the code. To get the length, you can use: jResult.Count(). I updated the code and added a constructor to get the length of your array.

Comment: Nice ! Thank you, I was really stuck with that !

Comment: You are welcome, you can now accept it as an answer as reference to others :) @Louuss

Comment: Done ! Just one thing, I just realised, in your second listing, it should be in the for loop :    x<intCount   instead of     x<=intCount    otherwise the indicator gets out of range ! And thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

You could either use

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
```

And then loop over the inner array yourself.
Or, you could create a class

```
class Foo {
    public List<List<Document>> result { get; set; }
}
```

And then you would access the inner array by accessing result[0] (given that the outer array is always of length 1).

Comment: I tried using the List<ListDocument>> and deserialize my JSON using that model, I can access the inner Array (ASP.NET recognize my Document model in the view) but when I try to access the inner array, I have every int = 0 and every string empty, is there something I missed ? For exemple some attribute to add in the Document class so the serializer knows what is what?